# Cómo saber si tengo el driver correcto para empezar a programar apps en mi celular

Tags: android-studio, usb

Utilizo android studio en windows 11 y tengo un Xiaomi Poco F3, y aparentemente tengo instalado el último driver oficial de xiaomi (descargado de la página oficial) para que mis aplicaciones hechas en android studio corran en mi celular, cómo hago para saber que ya está instalado correctamente (ya activé modo developer y modo USB debug en mi celular antes de instalar el driver oficial de xiaomi).

[image: la siguiente imagen muestra el mensaje que recibo luego de hacer todo el proceso correctamente (aparentemente)]

Comment: Intenta correr alguna demo de las que trae android studio y la emulas en el telefono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber si tu driver funciona correctamente, en Android Studio, en la parte superior indicara el modelo del dispositivo conectado a tu computadora, de otra forma si tu driver no funciona o no esta conectado tu dispositivo fisico, se mostrarìa simplemente "No Devices" como se muestra en esta imagen:

[image: Android Studio Jorgesys]